# design custom toggle button in android

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

Can any body please tell me how to design the custom toggle button.

[image]

Comment: Googling also helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remeber you must have **9 patch** your image to make theme reponsive along all devices.

Also you should have **different image for thumb and track**.

then in this way you can make the similar sliding switch

```
<Switch android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_blue"
                android:track="@drawable/track_grey"
                android:textOn="Male"
                android:textOff="Female"/>
```